# Printing GPS coordinates to a text file

Tags: c

I am using nRF9160. I am trying to write the gps coordinates to a txt file But for some reason  the file dont create and nothing is being written. I am attaching the link for the original code and after that a sample of what I added.

[Gps Code Link](https://github.com/NordicPlayground/fw-nrfconnect-nrf/blob/master/samples/nrf9160/gps/src/main.c)

```
 float x;
 x = pvt.longitude ;
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("Output.txt", "w");
 fprintf(fp, "Gps coordinates: %f", x);
fclose(fp); 
enter code here
```

Comment: Are you writing C or C++ ? They are not the same. In C++ there is `std::ofstream` for output into files, in C there isnt.

Comment: You are setting X capital but printing x lowercase. Your program is probably segfaulting since x has some random uninitialized data. Try using more descriptive variables names, and if you're actually using C++, use the type-safe standard library I/O functions instead of fprintf.

Comment: The code snippet you've shown about will not even compile on its own. Can you show us more of your code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Did you check the value of `fp`? Where are you writing the file to on the nRF9160?

Comment: Search your filesystem for Output.txt

Comment: I tried it but for some reason the code compiles but no file to be found

Comment: If `fopen` fails for some reason, and belive me it often does, it returne NULL. You __must__ check if `fopen` returns NULL and handle that case.

Comment: if `fopen` succeeded then the output file should be created in the current directory (which may not be the folder where the executable file resides)